# Ibatis" Need to manage connections/datasources independently

Tags: jdbc, connection, datasource, ibatis

The design of our application forces us to obtain our jdbc conncetions independently of the Ibatis session. We need a way to hand the connection (or alternately a datasource) to Ibatis and say "use this".

Have tries every search imaginable and can't find help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, then you may configure your own JNDI that will be used by your application to get DataSource/Connection objects. Also you may pass this configured JNDI into iBatis:

```
<transactionManager type="EXTERNAL">
    <dataSource type="JNDI">
        <property name="DataSource"
            value="java:comp/env/jdbc/someDataSource"/>
    </dataSource>
</transactionManager>
```